# Measuring achieved compression ratio of Kafka producer batches

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Kafka producer config allows you to configure `batch.size` and `compression.type`. I gather messages are concatenated into batches and then the specified compression algorithm is applied to that batch - correct me if I'm wrong.

Is there a straightforward way to measure the achieved compression ratio? Can I get a reference to the batches in code, by way of a listener perhaps, and query their size that way? Does Kafka emit relevant metrics by default?

**Edit**

I see that in `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.SenderMetrics.updateProduceRequestMetrics`, the metrics `records-per-batch`, `bytes` and `compression-rate` are emitted per topic each time a batch of records is processed.

I also see that `ProducerConfig.METRIC_REPORTER_CLASSES_CONFIG` allows you to provide a class that can be constructed with a zero args constructor and notified whenever a new metric is registered.

Finally, on my `KafkaStreams` object I can call `kafkaStreams.metrics()` to get a dictionary of `Metric` objects. So I can do something like

```
for (MetricName metricName: kafkaStreams.metrics().keySet())
{
    if (metricName.name().equals("compression-rate"))
    {
        System.out.println(((Metric) kafkaStreams.metrics().get(metricName)).metricValue());
    {
}
```

to get the value of the metric at any given time.

So I'm getting closer, but ideally I'd like to get a callback every time a new value of the metric is published. Is this possible?

Comment: Is what you're looking for any different than `compression-rate-avg` in producer serder metrics? https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producer_sender_monitoring

Comment: There is no way to get a callback. That is not how metrics work.